# How to change a pointer value between functions

Tags: c, pointers, char

I am new to C, and am confused on how to change the value of a `char *` between functions.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void testing(char *s) {
        s = "hi";
} // testing

int main() {
        char *s = "hello";
        testing(s);
        printf("%s\n", s);
} // main
```

In this case, the value of s is not changed, and `"hello"` is printed.

How can I change `s`, without having to change the return type or parameters of either function?

Comment: It's unfortunately very hard to answer this question in a good manner. The reason is that you don't seem to have sufficient basic knowledge about pointers and string literals. I could write code that kind of works for you, but that would be confusing. I recommend reading about strings, pointers and string literals.

Comment: @klutt. I dunno, I kinda like my answer

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm not sure. I get the feeling that while it is technically correct, I doubt that it teaches OP what he really needs to know.

Comment: @klutt. Barring the fact that we can never truly know what is in someone's mind, I've made an update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C function calls are strictly pass-by-value. This means that when you pass `s` to `testing`, a local copy is made. Assigning a new value to `s` in the function will therefore not affect the value in `main`.

Since the value of the pointer is copied, however, you can access the memory it points to. If `s` points to memory that isn't read-only, you could copy the contents of one buffer to another. For example, instead of `s = "hi";`,

```
strcpy(s, "hi");
```

In `main`, the statement `char *s = "hello";` is likely to have `s` point to a read-only buffer. To make it a writable buffer, declare `s` as an array instead:

```
 char s[] = "hello";
```

If you want to change the value of the pointer, rather than what it points to, you need to pass in the address of the memory containing `main`'s version of `s`: a pointer to a pointer. That would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void testing(char **s) {
        *s = "hi";
} // testing

int main() {
        char *s = "hello";
        testing(&s);
        printf("%s\n", s);
} // main
```

Another (perhaps better in this context) way is to use return values instead of parameters for both input and output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *testing(char *s) {
        s = "hi";
        return s;
} // testing

int main() {
        char *s = "hello";
        s = testing(s);
        printf("%s\n", s);
} // main
```

Answer (score 3):

In `main`, `char *s` is initialized to the string literal `"hello"`. This means `s` will be pointing to an anonymous array of 6 `char` containing the values `{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', o', '\0' }`. However, the contents of this array are not modifiable as far as the standard is concerned, so any code that writes to this array exhibits *undefined behavior*.

In the call to `testing`, the parameter `char *s` is treated as a local variable within the function. Any change to the pointer value will not affect the `char *s` variable in `main`. In C function calls, all parameters are passed *by value*.

Within `testing`, you change `s` to point to another string literal `"hi"`. Similar to the initialization in `main`, `testing`'s `s` will now point to an anonymous array of 3 `char` containing the values `{ 'h', 'i', '\0' }`. The contents of this anonymous array are not modifiable. As mentioned above, this has no effect on `main`'s `s` pointer.

You stated that you do not wish to modify the parameters or return type of either function. In order to do that, `testing` will need to overwrite the contents of the array pointed to by its parameter `s`. Since the current code in `main` has `s` pointing to a non-modifiable array, you will need to change it to point to a modifiable array. This can be done by changing `main`'s `s` into an array instead of a pointer:

```
int main() {
        char s[] = "hello"; // N.B. s[] is 6 chars long including the null terminator
        testing(s);
        printf("%s\n", s);
} // main
```

Then you can change `testing` to overwrite the contents of the array pointed to by its parameter `s`:

```
#include <string.h>

void testing(char *s) {
        strcpy(s, "hi");
} // testing
```

I have made use of the `strcpy` standard library function in the above version of `testing`.

It is up to you to ensure that you do not write too many `char`s to the array pointed to by `s`.

The length of array `s` in main has been automatically set to 6 by the initializer "hello" (5 characters plus a null terminator character). You can set the length of the array explicitly if you need to overwrite more than 6 `char`s including the null terminator:

```
    char s[100] = "hello";  // s[100] has space for 99 characters plus a null terminator.
```

Answer (score 2):

Functions receive only copies of argument values:

```
void f(int x)          // x is a new variable that is initialized to the argument value.
{
    x = x + 3;         // Adds 3 to the local x.
    printf("%d\n", x); // Prints 8.
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 5;
    f(x);              // Passes 5, not x, to f.
    printf("%d\n", x); // Prints 5, not 8.
}
```

You can get a value back from a function by returning it:

```
int f(int x)           // Function is changed to return int.
{
    x = x + 3;         // Adds 3 to the local x.
    printf("%d\n", x); // Prints 8.
    return x;          // Returns new value.
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 5;
    x = f(x);          // Set x from the value returned by the function.
    printf("%d\n", x); // Prints 8.
}
```

You can also get a value back from a function by having the function change the value of an object. To do this, you must provide the address of the object to the function:

```
void f(int *p)          // p is a pointer to an int.
{
    *p = *p + 3;        // Adds 3 to the pointed-to int.
    printf("%d\n", *p); // Prints 8.
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 5;
    f(&x);             // Passes address of x to f.
    printf("%d\n", x); // Prints 8.
}
```

If you want a function to change a pointer, you can pass the address of a pointer:

```
void f(char **p)       // p is a pointer to a pointer to a char.
{
    *p = "hi"          // Sets *p to point to (first character of) "hi".
    printf("%s\n", x); // Prints "hi".
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s = "hello"; // Sets s to point to (first character of) "hello".
    f(&s);             // Passes address of s to f.
    printf("%s\n", x); // Prints "hi".
}
```